# Picasso: Call fetch on same URL multiple times

Tags: android, fetch, picasso

I want to pre-fetch images using the Picasso library. In the documentation of Picasso I find the [description for fetch](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--)

```
public void fetch():

Asynchronously fulfills the request without a ImageView or Target. This is useful when you want to warm up the cache with an image.
Note: It is safe to invoke this method from any thread.
```

For *into(...)* the behaviour is obviously that Picasso takes the image from the cache (if still available).
But ***what happens when I call fetch multiple times for the same image / url? Is the image re-fetched (from the network) or does Picasso find the image in the cache?***